# Meaning of 'netstat -anto' output

Tags: networking, tcp

I did `netstat -anto` and got following result:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       Timer

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1169              127.0.0.1:40238            ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

what this time `off` mean?

does it mean keepalive is off?
if yes then how to enable keep alive?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/240456/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-netstat-o-netstat-timers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/240456/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-netstat-o-netstat-timers) describes as best is generally known the meaning of the Timer field. "off" means not any of the a number of things including keepalive. So on that socket keepalive is off.

The thing that sets up the socket on port 1169 needs to enable keepalive. Since that's a totally different topic and will have nothing to do with the title, I suggest closing this one off, and starting another question regarding how to set keepalive on the program that is running on port 1169.